# Warning Error unreachable code in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My reactjs app has a warning unreachable code no-unreachable, has anyone ever experienced or helped my problem

the error if else return statement

the error is in the section :
            
            
        )
    }
return (

Thank you in advance

```js
const listNews = [];
    if (<Route path="/berita/:id" component={ViewsBerita} />) {
        return(
            <div>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={8}>
                    <div className={classes.section} style={styleTitle}>
                        <div className={classes.container}>
                            <HashRouter>
                                <Route path="/berita/:id" component={ViewsBerita} />
                            </HashRouter>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </GridItem>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return(
            <div>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={7}>
                    <div style={style}>
                        <ul>
                            {renderTodos}
                        </ul>
                        <br />
                        <ul style={pagination}>
                            {renderPrevBtn}
                            {pageDecrementBtn}
                            {renderPageNumbers}
                            {pageIncrementBtn}
                            {renderNextBtn}
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </GridItem>       
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Headers />   
    
        <div className={classNames(classes.main, classes.mainRaised)} key="i">
          <br />
          
          <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
              <div className={classes.section} style={styleTitle}>
                <div className={classes.container}>
                  <h1> <b> Berita & Event </b> </h1>
                  <div style={{ width: '25%', marginLeft: '37%' }}>
                    <p style={{ border: '1px solid', borderColor: 'yellow'}} > </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </GridItem>

            {listNews}
            </GridContainer>
          <Footers />
        </div>
        <Footer />
        <ScrollToTop showUnder={160} style={{zIndex: 100 }}>
          <span> <img src={Up} alt="up" style={{ width: '40px', height: '40px' }} /> </span>
        </ScrollToTop>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default withStyles(componentsStyle)(Components);
```

My reactjs app has a warning unreachable code no-unreachable, has anyone ever experienced or helped my problem

the error if else return statement

the error is in the section :
            
            
        )
    }
return (

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

That is because that last `return` statement will never work. You already have an `if...else` statement. Which means either of that will work and either of that will return (either the `if` condition or the `else` condition will work), and your code will never under any circumstances go to the last return statement and therefore that code is unreachable.

Comment: then how to make this code work? What should I do @illiteratewriter